# Is there any way to force the Mac to not to log me out after ten minutes?

Tags: macos, display, system-settings, screensaver

With this setting on the Mac Mini:

[image]

The <s>screensaver comes on</s> the screen turns off after ten minutes or so. This has just happened three times running.

Is there another setting which makes the Mac keep me logged in, with applications running?

Cleverly, it shuts down Apple Music, which loses its place (usually -- while reproducing the bug I left Safari foregrounded on the draft of this question, and the Mac was stopped short of killing Apple Music by the edit page's "discard" prompt -- but the screensaver still came on, with password). When I log back in, it's off the track I was listening to when the Mac lost the plot, and back on the default urgent advertisement for Taylor Swift.

Comment: Is it the *screensaver* that comes on (some swirly colors or photos), or does the screen *turn off*!?

Comment: @deceze No colors or photos, so it must have been turning the screen off. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your power saver settings might be overriding this. Set them such that display is not turned off for a longer time.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202824

Additionally, you should check "Logout after n minutes" in Security and  Privacy-> General -> Advanced.

Comment: Well, I'll be. Looks like that was it. Testing now. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure that did entirely work. Left it for a while, came back, and the screen was still on for a change, but there was a "Safari interrupted logout" prompt.

Comment: @EdPlunkett check the edit.

Comment: @edplunkett well I crossed 2000 and finishing touch was this post. :)

Comment: Congratulations!